# How to exclude else value from Regex conditional formula and only show the matched conditions?

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I'm adding a custom dimenensions to my Looker Studio using a regex_match formula, all my conditions are correct I just would like to exclude the "else" values (just want to show those that match the condtions)

how do I please exclude the "else" capturing the unmatched conditions? tried to remove the else "other" but the unmatched conditions still appear as "null"

My code is below and I would like to only show the matched conditions

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing page, '.*example-123.*') THEN "Example" 
else "others"
end
```

Comment: Just remove `else "others"`?

Comment: The Unmatched conditions still appear as "null" after removing the else "others"

Comment: Do it in two steps : 1) Use your regexp to flag data that you want to keep and that you want to discard 2) Use a filter on the flag to keep only the data that matched the regexp

Comment: Thank you, Yes I ended up doing that which worked but was wondering if I could do that in one step in the regexp formula.